# can Dexterity store field (include uid or parentid) in sql?

Tags: plone, dexterity

Archetypes has a sqlstorage attribute when design the schema,how about the Dexterity?

Answer (score 2):

SQLStorage is deprecated and never really worked in the first place.  There is no equivalent for Dexterity, and there will not be.  If you need to deploy Plone with a SQL backend, you should use RelStorage, it is modern and battle-tested.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RelStorage

Comment: I wouldn't say "there will not be." Presumably a class could be created which was both an sqlalchemy ORM-mapped class and a Dexterity content class. But it would take quite some familiarity with multiple frameworks to make it work.

Comment: Well, fair enough.  The fact that Shane Hathaway declared this to be "too complicated to be worth pursuing" after several attempts seems like fairly strong, but admittedly not definitive, evidence to me. ;-)

Comment: David,do you have any sample about class herient from dexterity and sqlalchemy orm-class. The RelStorage is Last changed at 2011-11-12,does it alive?

Comment: RelStorage is in active use. Ask for existing users on the user list and you should be able to get practical feedback.

Comment: Be advised that RelStorage is not the same as or in any way equivalent to storing field values in an SQL table. RelStorage simply stores the ZODB in a relational database rather than in a flat file. It is still the ZODB underneath. This is useful for replication and such, but does not mean that the data is in any way 'relational'.